# Can I give the quick fix window a different status line in vim?

Tags: vim, statusline

I'd like to give the Quick Fix window a different status line than all my other windows.

I want it to have:

```
set statusline=\ %n\ \ %f%=%L\ lines\
```

When I'm in the quick fix window, I can use :setlocal, but how in my .vimrc can I make it have a different status line?

Comment: I didn't get this to work for my own status line string because I used quotes:
`set statusline="my status"`

Instead I had to use the format similar to the OP's question:
`set statusline=my\ status`

If you want quotes to be in your status lines:
`set statusline=he\ said\ \"hello\"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work

```
autocmd Filetype qf setlocal statusline=\ %n\ \ %f%=%L\ lines\
```

Comment: Thanks.  I only had to change "set" to "setlocal", and it's just what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

QuickFix window has filetype `qf` (see `:help filetype`), so you can add a line:

```
setlocal statusline=\ %n\ \ %f%=%L\ lines\
```

to appropriate `qf.vim` (see `:help ftplugin-overrule`).